# Android : Gestures on viewFlipper conflicting touch on GraphView which is inside in viewflipper

Tags: android, swipe, gesture, viewflipper, android-graphview

I am working on the application in which activity is updated from the background service. In the activity there are three views which receives the data from the service. To show these three views I used the viewFlipper, in which we be able to swipe the views left to right an vice versa by swipe gestures.

I used the **`GestureDetector`** for that. One of the view in viewflipper has Graphview (Bar Graph).  When I play with this graph for example pinch in/out or scrolls the viewFlipper changes to next view(I think it is considering this gesture for viewflipper).

so how to handle this problem? thanks in advance.